# Vim fastest way to replace words

Tags: python, search, vim, replace, text-editor

Sometimes I find myself wanting to replace just 2-3 long words in a program and I find it a bit painful in how I do it, just wondering if there is any Vim wizards out there that could give me a faster way of doing this:

```
var_wanted = {}
some_other_var = {}

def function1():
  ....
  ....
  some_other_var.append(...)
  ....
  some_other_var.append(...)
  some_other_var.append(...)
  ....
```

Now lets say I want to replace `some_other_var` with `var_wanted`, now usually the way I do this is I will go to var_wanted use `yiw` to copy the word to register, then move to the first instance of `some_other_var` do `viw` to select the word, then do `p` to paste it in and replace the word. However this process is not repeatable, I can't go to the next instance of some_other_var and type `.` because for some reason now `some_other_var` is in my register as opposed to `var_wanted`, I do this so often that I feel like I'm losing years of my life. And yes I am aware of using search and replace `:%s/some_other_var/var_watned/gc`, but I feel like this instance is for so few replacements that its not worth typing that whole thing out. Please heeelp

End product wanted:

```
var_wanted = {}
some_other_var = {}

def function1():
  ....
  ....
  var_wanted.append(...)
  ....
  var_wanted.append(...)
  var_wanted.append(...)
  ....
```

Comment: If you are not a vim wizard already then just use Vs Code or Pycharm community, stuff like that is so much easier in an IDE

Comment: @TomaszSwider I like Vim, I've been using it for a year and a half now. I'm not interested in using a bulky IDE. I'm trying to get better at vim.

Comment: Forward slash, var_wanted. `cw` to change word. `var_wanted` ESCAPE. `n` `.`

Comment: Specifically about `viwp` clobbering the register, use `viw"0p` instead, which won't clobber the previously yanked text from the `"0` register. (But note you can't repeat this with `.` anyways, since it's not a single command.) See [`:help v_p`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#v_p) which mentions `"0p` specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
Cursor on `var_wanted`: `"ayiw` (yank into register a).
Cursor on `some_old_var`: `ciw`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`ra`<kbd>Esc</kbd> (change word, insert contents of register a).
Put cursor on next `some_old_var`: `.` will do the previous action again.

---

Finding a keystroke series that's *shorter* than `%s/some_old_var/var_wanted/g` is going to be difficult.

> because for some reason now `some_other_var` is in my register

`viwp` is implicitly deleting the selected word. Deleted text in vim goes into the register. You can avoid this with `viw"_dP` instead, which explicitly deletes into the null register so it does not get copied, and then puts. Typing this 3 times seems worse than the `%s/` version.

---

If it's typing `var_wanted` and `some_other_var` that bothers you, you can yank them into registers (let's use `"f`ind and `"r`eplace for mnemonic purposes) via `"fyiw` and `"ryiw` when your cursor is in the right spots. Then you could just `%s:<C-r>f:<C-r>r:g` to do all the replaces (`<C-R>` means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>). The problem here is moving the cursor around and then yanking doesn't seem much faster than typing the word.

---

There's also `c`hanging things. If you had `some_old_var.`, you could position your cursor on the word and then `ciwvar_wanted`, which would remove `some_old_var` and enter insert mode where you would type `var_wanted`. The benefit to this is after leaving insert mode, you could use `.` when your cursor is on the next instance of `some_old_var` and it would repeat the whole action, replacing `some_old_var` with `var_wanted`.

Another useful note is that if `var_wanted` is super long (and exists in this file already), you can use `C-n` to autocomplete after you've typed a few characters of the word. This would still work with `.` after you finished the insert.

If you really want to avoid typing any amount of `var_wanted`, you can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> in insert mode as well, meaning you can yank `var_wanted` by putting your cursor on it and using `"ayiw` (to yank into register a) and then putting your cursor on `some_old_var` and doing `ciw<C-R>a` to replace it.

Comment: You can create a mapping to for this sort of workflow: `nnoremap gs *``:%s///g<left><left>`. It might get a little jumpy with `*` and backtick-backtick. I leave that as an exercise for the reader

Answer (score 0):

As long as your desired register is the yank register:

```
:%s/some_other_var/\=@0/g
```

The above solution is good if you are trying to change a large number of occurences of the "some_other_var"

You can also use the "gn" approach, see `:h gn`, in my case I have:

```
:nnoremap c* *<c-o>cgn
```

copy the "var_wanted" move to the first "some_other_var" and then press:

```
c* ...................... triggers our mapping
<Ctrl-r>0 ................ paste the yank register
<Esc> .................... leave insert mode
.  ....................... now press dot as much as you want
```

To learn more about the `gn` trick watch this amazing video:
http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/